# NoClassDefFound org/slf4j/impl/staticloggerbinder

Tags: hibernate, noclassdeffounderror

iam deleloping application in struts 1.2.7 and liferay 6.0.6 i am using hibernate3,hibernate-annotations jar files , when i deploy the war file in jBOSS then it is giving me this error **NoClassDefFound  org/slf4j/impl/staticloggerbinder** , to remove this error i copied slf4j-log4j12 from  **[LIFERAY_HOME]\jboss-5.1.0\server\default\deploy\ROOT.war\WEB-INF\lib** to my

server defualt lib i.e **[LIFERAY_HOME]\jboss-5.1.0\server\default\lib** then error gets removed but some other error i.e **class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings**
and the 2 locations are
1)[LIFERAY_HOME]\jboss-5.1.0\server\default\deploy\ROOT.war\WEB-INF\lib
2) [LIFERAY_HOME]\jboss-5.1.0\server\default\lib

now really confused that what is happening. what is this error NoClassDefFound  org/slf4j/impl/staticloggerbinder i serached on google but its hibernate3 related error my concern is that what to do to remove this error and what staticloggerbinder this class does is it realeted to hibernate or something else

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the log4j is loaded from two different class loaders, from ROOT (Liferay) and from shared class loader (\server\default\lib). You have two alternative solution:

1. Move slf4j-logXXX.jar & log4j.jar from ROOT/.../lib to shared class loader (`\server\default\lib`)
2. Set enviroment variable `log4j.ignore.TCL=true` (ignore class loader)